# Can someone make my Jquery suck less?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I feel *really* dumb for asking this question, but here it goes.  I have an asp.net page that may (or may not) load text boxes on the page with Ajax depending on if certain checkboxes and other conditions are met. I also need these boxes to be hidden given certain conditions.  For the use case where the text boxes are on the page during the load having my jquery in the document ready does the trick.  For the other use case where the text boxes are loaded with a particular user action, the code in document ready will have no effect.  I ended up taking the bulk out of document ready and placed it in its own function called "setup" which I can call after the text boxes have been loaded.

So here is the problem:  I can't figure out how to have the page call setup after those text boxes are loaded.  I can't use .ajaxComplete() (probably because asp.net isn't using jquery to load those boxes) nor can I think of any other way to call setup at the right time. The only thing I could think of was to have the page call setup on mouseover.

This is unnecessarily greedy and frankly just really bad code.  Is there an easy way to call "setup" once after those boxes are loaded?

```
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setup("ready");

      });

      function setup(action)
      {
        if(action=="ready" || $("#<%=CurrentInventoryMode.ClientID %> option:selected").val()==1)
        {
         if(!$('#<%=AllowSub.ClientID %>').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('#<%=InStockUnits.ClientID %>').hide();
            $('#<%=LowStockUnits.ClientID %>').hide();
            $('#SellAsSpan').hide();
            $('#<%=SellAsUnit.ClientID %>').hide();
        }
        if($("#<%=SellAsUnit.ClientID %> option:selected").val()==4)
        {
            removeWeight();
        }else{
            removeMeasure();
        }
        }
       }

       $('body').mouseover(function()
       {
       //there has GOT to be a better way....
        setup();
       });
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the part of the code that does the ajax call.  Its an ajax update panel

```
<ajax:UpdatePanel ID="InventoryAjax" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="CurrentInventoryMode" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CurrentInventoryMode_SelectedIndexChanged" onclick="setup();">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Disabled"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Track Product"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Track Variants"/>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I tried putting setup in the onclick, but it fires before the boxes load so its kind of worthless :(.

Comment: Can't you invoke a function as a callback once your Ajax is completed?

Comment: `<%=` should be outside the strings.

Comment: @SergioTapia Thats what I would like to do.  The only way I know how to do that is with .ajaxComplete, and that isn't working.

Comment: Can we see your ajax load code (even if its asp). @SergioTapia - I don't use ASP, but maybe he has a timing issue between ASP loaded elements and jQuery. For instance, if the AJAX callback is initiated once the data is transferred, but not after the elements are added to the DOM.

Comment: @mrtsherman: Ah that is a possibility, I'm afraid I don't use ASP.Net Webforms, I use MVC3.

Comment: "I can't use .ajaxComplete() (probably because asp.net isn't using jquery to load those boxes)" <-- are you using an update panel?

Comment: I never used UpdatePanel, but maybe you can inline script the call to setup() in the response.

Comment: I normally wouldn't use them either, but I'm changing someone else's code.  If I can change the response that would be perfect.  Looks like I have research to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdatePanels replace the HTML when updated. So the new HTML needs to be rebound. Here is a javascript block to get you going:

```
    function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
        // There are two arrays (created and updated). Treat them separately if if makes sense
        var updatePanels = args.get_panelsUpdated().concat(args.get_panelsCreated());
        for (var i = 0; i < updatePanels.length; i++) {
            if (updatePanels[i].id == "<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>"){
                // code to bind contents of UpdatePanel1
            }
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Handle updatepanel updates
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
    });
```

Comment: I put an alert in the //code to bind part, but it is never fired, even when the html is updated from the update panel

Comment: After reading some information the code you posted I was able to figure it out!  Thanks a bunch!